# Error message when migrating Core Data store

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

**The Problem:**

I've got some pretty simple code (below) that causes an exception during '`migratePersistentStore`' with the error message

```
Exception:*** -[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: object cannot be nil
```

**The Code:**

```
NSPersistentStore * oldStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores][0];

if (oldStore) {

    @try {

        [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:oldStore 
              toURL:[self storeURL] 
              options: @{ NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption : @YES } 
              withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

    }
    @catch(NSException* ex) {

        NSLog(@"Exception:%@", ex.description);

    }

}
```

**Further Info:**

- It appears that if no data is present, the exception does not occur. Instead the same function sets an error, with userInfo "**Can't add the same store twice**".
- I'm currently making a small simple project to try and replicate the problem, I'll post a link here once it's done.

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one: http://pastebin.com/g0Mcd9SK

Comment: Did you see this topic:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768380/migrate-persistant-store-crash. There discussed the same problem.

Comment: @VladimirPopko no I didn't see that. Hmmm, I'm not sure about the proposed answer because it just copies files around without worrying about things like migrating metadata. If it's possible to get the proper way of migrating stores to work, I'd like to do that instead!

Comment: You are right they suggest not the best way. BTW could you attach to the topic your old and new versions of data model? Is there any chance that Core Data can't migrate your store automatically and you need do it manually by code?

Comment: @Visput the data model hasn't actually changed in this instance, so no migration should be occuring - in fact if I take out the migration options the problem is still there. What I did notice though is that when no managed objects exist, the error doesn't occur.

Comment: @Visput in fact, there's a different error that occurs when no data is present. No exception occurs, but the function logs an error: "Can't add the same store twice".

Comment: It seems that old store has already copied to new one. Did you try to delete application from device and install it from scratch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, Core Data doesn't like migration when your iCloud URL and local URL are the same. I thought this shouldn't matter because really, iCloud data is stored in its own directory. BUT, it seems during migration, using the same name causes problems.

Easy fix - just do something like this:

```
- (NSURL *)storeURL {

    NSURL * documentsDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:NULL];

    if (iCloudEnabled]) {
        return [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"iCloudEventData.sqlite"];
    } else {
        return [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"EventData.sqlite"];
    }

}
```

Comment: if you were able to resolve your issue, can you close out the question?

Comment: @quellish yep, I've accepted my answer as correct. I can't award the bounty to myself, so correct me if there's nothing more that I can do to close it out currently?

Comment: I'm afraid you also have to do a victory dance.

Answer (score 5):

There really isn't enough information here to tell you the exact cause. As you may have guessed, CoreData is running into a problem where it is replacing an object in an array with a nil object. This can happen if your mapping models do not match correctly.

To troubleshoot your problem, you should do two things:

1. Remove that try/catch an instead set a symbolic breakpoint for all exceptions. This will cause the debugger to stop when it hits this exception, and you can see the stack trace and everything else that is going on in your application. Note that if CoreData runs into merge conflicts these are handled inside CoreData as exceptions and the debugger will stop on those as well. In that case, just continue until your array exception.
2. Set your application's launch arguments to turn on migration logging to see how it's getting to this point. In Xcode, edit your application scheme's Run task to pass `-com.apple.CoreData.MigrationDebug`. Note that the dash preceding the argument is important. CoreData will log what happens during your migration, which should help pinpoint the problem.

[image: What your scheme should look like]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I've actually done both, and it stops on migratePersistentStore. Unfortunately from the stack trace I can't see anything out of place. The migration debug option doesn't seem to provide any output either. Currently I'm making a small sample project to replicate the issue - I'll post a link here once it's done. That way there should be plenty of information for anyone to replicate :)

Answer (score 2):

A random guess: do you have any `NSManagedObject` subclasses declared in your model that you've forgotten to include an implementation for in your build? In that case it's imaginable that the migration code might attempt to create an instance of the custom subclass, fail to do so, then fail to check that it succeeded before throwing the result into an array.

Run without a migration and perform something like this to check:

```
for(NSEntityDescription *entityDescription in model.entities)
{
    NSString *className = [entityDescription managedObjectClassName];
    Class class = NSClassFromString(className);

    if(className && !class)
        NSLog(@"An implementation of class %@ is missing from the build", 
            className);
}
```

Comment: Hey Tommy, great idea. Unfortunately I placed the code just before migrating the store and no luck, all of my NSManagedObject subclasses are accounted for.