# Error On CoreData Persistent Store Migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, migration, icloud

i'm experimenting with iCloud Sync in my CoreData enabled Application. So far everything works fine but now i want to add an iCloud On/Off Toggle in Settings and on toggle Migrate my Persistent Store from iCloud to Local or vice versa so that the User doesn't lose his Data.

When I First setup the CoreData Persistent I Ask the User if he wants to use iCloud and if he answers yes i setup the `persistentStore` using:

```
[self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                       configuration:nil
                                                                                 URL:self.storeURL
                                                                             options:@{ NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : @"iCloudStore" }
                                                                               error:&error];
```

If he answers No i Will just pass `nil` as the options parameter.

When the User toggles the Migration(in this example from iCloud To Local) I perform the Migration like this:

```
//Migrate
__weak NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *currentStore = [[psc persistentStores] firstObject];
[psc migratePersistentStore:currentStore <------------------ this fails
                      toURL:self.storeURL
                    options:@{ NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption : @YES }
                   withType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                      error:&error];
if(error){
    NSLog(@"migrateType:%@ migrateError:%@ userInfo:%@",migrateType,migrateError,[migrateError userInfo]);
    return;
}
self.useCloud = NO;
//Reloading the Store afterwards....
```

According to "[This](http://www.objc.io/issue-10/icloud-core-data.html#icloud_on__off_switch)" and "[This](https://github.com/mluisbrown/iCloudCoreDataStack/issues/4)".
i should be able to use the same "storeURL" for both the cloud and local store but unfortunately the migration fails with the error:

```
migrateType:toLocal migrateError:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134080 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134080.)" UserInfo=0x12a1f0a0 {NSUnderlyingException=Can't add the same store twice} userInfo:{
NSUnderlyingException = "Can't add the same store twice";
```

I am aware that i should be able to solve this using a different local and cloud URL but since this would complicate things a lot i would rather use the same URL all the time.

Any Ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in Advance

p.s.:
Store URL method:

```
- (NSURL*)storeURL{
NSURL* documentsDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:NULL];
return [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"nameIsNotImportant.sqlite"];
}
```

p.s.s: **its iOS7**

Comment: oops sorry forgot to mention its iOS 7.

Comment: As far as I know, you need to use different URLs. Pretty sure I read that yesterday in the guide to iCloud in Core Data too.

Comment: May be its too late but according to the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876784/error-message-when-migrating-core-data-store Core Data doesn't like migration when your iCloud URL and local URL are the same, please have a look at the post.